# google-services.json, как с ним быть с точки зрения заливки на github?

Tags: android, github

Собственно вопрос в том, насколько безопасно включать данный файл в репозиторий проекта на github? С одной стороны там внутри ключи API, но с другой - без него проект то не собирается и если разработчиков больше одного (да даже если один, но с разных компов), то это большая проблема.

Как вообще подходить к решению этой дилеммы?

Comment: при сборке приложения этот файл попадает в него как есть?

Comment: @MikhailVaysman насколько я понимаю - да. Понятное дело, что всегда можно вытащить его из APK, но это будет целевая атака на конкретно это приложение, а вот файл в открытом репе на гитхабе любой дурак автоматом обнаружит

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Заливать его в репу не стоит - там важные секретные данные. Надо добавить его в `.gitignore`. Если он требуется нескольким разработчикам, то надо указать в `README` что он требуется и нужным людям выдавать сам файл для ручного вставления в проект либо выдавать им доступ к проекту в `Firebase` чтобы они сами его качали.